# Fluentd how to get source from a file by executing a script

Tags: fluentd

I have a script called `script.py`. After running the script, I get different/various `.log` files in a folder. How do I write a config file which runs the script and then sends a log file successfully?

Here is my configuration which appears to be getting no output from match `@type` stdout:

```
<source>
  @type exec
  tag sensor_1.log-raw-data
  command python /home/cool/Desktop/script.py
  run_interval 5m
  <parse>
    keys something
  </parse>
</source>

<source>
  @type tail
  read_from_head true
  path /home/cool/Desktop/logs/0slaprunner.log
  tag foo.*
  <parse>
    @type none
  </parse>
</source>

<match pattern>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument for `match` section is `pattern`. It means that this would cater for the events with tag `pattern`. But, none of the tags in `source` sections is `pattern`; hence, no routing to `stdout`.

From your description, it looks like you want to route events from the `tail` input plugin to the `stdout` output plugin, so the relevant configuration would be something like this:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  # ...
  tag foo           # tag for the events
  # ...
</source>

<match foo>         # cater events with tag `foo`
  @type stdout
</match>
```

For debugging purposes, run `fluentd` with `-v` or `-vv` command-line option.